# convert numerical date to weekdays

Tags: ruby, date

Is there a way to convert a numerical date to a weekday without writing a calendar? I want to go from: `"11/01/2015"` to `"Sun 11"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way

```
[arup@ruby]$ irb
>> require 'date'
=> true
>> Date.strptime("11/01/2015", "%d/%m/%Y")
=> #<Date: 2015-01-11 ((2457034j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> Date.strptime("11/01/2015", "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%a %d")
=> "Sun 11"
```

Comment: thanks. what's the difference between _strptime and strptime?

Comment: @ZachSmith [_strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_strptime) gives a `Hash`, whereas [strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) gives a Date object.

Comment: Jan 11 2015 is Sunday not Saturday. You need Captical `Y`, that's why it shows 2020-01-11 in your first example of Date.strptime. Here is the fix `Date.strptime("11/01/2015", "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%a %d")`

Comment: You can use `Date.parse` for this.

Comment: @JikkuJose `#parse` is not a good practice always. There are many cases it will fail. `strptime` is _strict_, the format you will give it, it will accept only that, otherwise _Argument error_. `#parse` blindly accepts various type of arguments..You even wouldn't be able to know which format of date you are getting.

Comment: @ArupRakshit yes, but for standard formatting shouldn't `#parse` be suggested? It makes code much more readable & significant majority of cases will have fixed formatting input sources, if it works for in one case, it should on all other similar inputs.

Comment: @JikkuJose No.. I explained why _No_ ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit perhaps my inexperience makes me think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
>> require 'date'
=> true
>> Date.parse("11/01/2015").strftime("%a %d")                                                     
=> "Sun 11"
```

Comment: I agree @Arup Rakshit's option , think of this case, in some countries, the time format is MONTH/DATE/YEAR, in this case, your command will fail. `Date.parse("01/13/2015").strftime("%a %d")`

Comment: I didn't vote it down. I also hate these persons who voted down without comments.